# Associative array - PERL

Tags: arrays, perl, associative-array

I need to know the way of creating the Associative array in Perl.

Basically now I have the code which is implemented as follows:

```
 my $getEmployeeListOfTeamQuery  = "SELECT profiles.userid 
                                  FROM user_group_map,profiles 
                                  WHERE user_group_map.group_id = $teamId 
                                  AND profiles.userid = user_group_map.user_id 
                                  AND profiles.active = 'y' 
                                  AND profiles.login_name NOT LIKE 'qa_%' 
                                  AND profiles.disabledtext = '' 
                                  GROUP BY profiles.login_name 
                                  ORDER BY profiles.login_name";

    my $getEmployeeListOfTeam = $dbh->prepare($getEmployeeListOfTeamQuery);
    $getEmployeeListOfTeam -> execute();
    my @techs = ();

    while(my ($tech) - $getEmployeeListOfTeam->fetchrow_array) {
        push @techs,$tech;
    }
```

So above code will be having the query in $getEmployeeListOfTeamQuery, Created the array names as techs.

Then tried pushing the values in to the the array.

Here it is working fine.

My question here is regarding the creation of associative array.

That is I need to query as follows : "SELECT profiles.userid, profiles,username....."

Hence I need to create a Associative array with "userid" as key and "username" as value.

Comment: You have to use ->fetchrow_hashref (instead of fetchrow_array). This way you obtain a ref to an associative array (hash)

Comment: Remember: given an hash ref $href you can use the syntax $href->{'key'} to get the value associated to 'key'

Comment: @frhack: If you read the question carefully, you will see that the OP is not asking for the data structure that `fetchrow_hashref()` returns.

Comment: He needs "to create a Associative array" from a dbi query. So the answer is use "$href = $sth->fetchrow_hashref"

Comment: @frhack No, that's not the answer.

Comment: @frhack: Read the question more closely. The key in the hash is one column from each row and the value is another. That is not what `fetchrow_hashref()` gives you. Using `fetchrow_hashref()` would give a data structure like `{ userid => "foo", username => "bar" }`. The question asks for a structure like `{ foo => "bar"}`.

Comment: ok ok ok .... sorry what a my mistake... I apologize  !!! Please see my new answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worry about the resources that you are using to learn Perl. Perl programmers haven't used the term "associative array" since Perl 5 was released over twenty years ago. We now call these structures "hashes". If you're learning from resources that use the term "associative array", then they are almost certainly horribly outdated.

But, to answer your question. The code is pretty simple.

```
my $sql = 'select profiles.userid, profiles.username...';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute;

my %techs_hash;
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
  $techs_hash{$row[0]} = $row[1];
}
```

Comment: *Associative array* is formal CS language, and it refers to that which the Perl "hash" is implementing (actually a hash table, I suppose). In formal CS language, *hash* refers to either the *hash function* itself or the output of a hash function, the *hash value*, not an associative array. I cannot really cite this, but a quick search on `scholar.google.com` or perusing some CS textbooks might yield quantitatively sufficient evidence that this information is true, and is not outdated by 20 years.

Comment: @JonathanKomar: I understand all of that. But my point stands that if you're using Perl resources that use the term, (unless they say something like "hashes are Perl's implementation of associative arrays") then they are likely to be rather outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`selectcol_arrayref()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#selectcol_arrayref) and the `Columns` attribute:

```
my $aref = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref('select userid, login_name ...', {Columns => [1, 2]});
my %hash = @$aref;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch all rows into hash of hashes by one call to selectall_hashref:

```
 my $tech=$dbh->selectall_hashref("select profile.userid, profiles.username, ...",'userid');
```

or you can fetch all rows into array of hashes with selectall_arrayref with attribute `{Slice=>{}}` :

```
my $tech=$dbh->selectall_arrayref("select profile.userid, profiles.username, ...",{Slice=>{}});
```

and then turn it into desired hash (this is exactly what you want):

```
my $result;
$result->{$_->{userid}}=$_->{username} foreach @$tech;
```

Comment: Only the second option does what the question asked, and it's not very efficient with no additional benefit.

Comment: additional benefit here is a shorter code  - why write those `prepare execute while fetch` things when they are already (and quite efficiently) implemented in selectall_* subs ?

Comment: "this is exactly what you want" - well, the question asks for a hash and you have given us a hash reference. Not sure that's "exactly what you want" :-)  Perhaps `my %result; $result{$_->{userid}}=$_->{username} foreach @$tech;` would be a little closer :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
my @l;
while(my $h = $sth->fetchrow_hashref){
  push @l,$h;
}
my %hash;
map { $hash{$_->{userid}} = $_->{username} } @l;
```

Comment: Why not assign the hash inside the `while` loop? `while (...) { $hash{$h->{userid}} = $h->{username}; }`. Not sure why you'd want to add in that extra loop.

Comment: You are right but here I wanted propose a lambda style. The map function is one of the fundamental instrument.
http://reactivex.io/learnrx/

Comment: `my %hash = map { $_->{userid} => $_->{username} } @{ $sth->fetchall_arrayref({}) };`

Comment: @DaveCross perfect answer !